# Getting error message when trying to connect SQL/DB2 DB [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, sqlconnection, dbeaver

When trying to connect to the database using the ODBC driver. I am getting this error message.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

This is a IBM DB2 database where I am using ODBC driver. Any help is appreciated. Not sure what the issue is ???

I downloaded an older version of dbeaver that has the ODBC driver.  This DB can only be connected via ODBC driver only.

Comment: sounds like you're using incorrect driver. why would sql server trying to access a DB2-database

Comment: ODBC is just an API specification that gives applications a common method to access different types of databases, but you still need vendor-specific drivers to actually connect to particular types of databases. If you're trying to connect to one of IBM's DB2 databases have you installed [IBM's DB2 ODBC driver](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-odbc-cli-driver-download-and-installation-information)? Also, DBeaver Java-based, so you're probably actually needing JDBC drivers for DB2. Have you read through [Connect to DB2 Data in DBeaver](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/db2-jdbc-dbvr.rst) yet?